# How to enumerate through list of Func<TSource,TResult> to filter collection

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, lambda

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to enumerate through a `List<Func<InstagramUser,bool>>` to filter a collection of `List<InstagramUser>`. My code compiles, but just returns the whole list, unfiltered, when `display()` is invoked.

My question is, what is the proper way to hold a collection of lambda expressions that can then be used to filter another collection?

```
public class InstagramDisplay {
    public IList<InstagramUser> instagramUsers;
    public IList<Func<InstagramUser, bool>> instagramFilters; 

    public InstagramDisplay() {
        instagramUsers = new List<InstagramUser>();
        instagramFilters = new List<Func<InstagramUser, bool>>();
    }

    public void addFilter(Func<InstagramUser, bool> filter, object filterValue) {
        if ((int)(filterValue ?? 0) > 0)
            instagramFilters.Add(filter);
    }

    public IEnumerable<InstagramUser> display() { //filter not working
        instagramFilters.ToList().ForEach(filter => instagramUsers.Where(filter));
        return instagramUsers;
    }
}
```

Invocation - just returns full collection, unfiltered:

```
InstagramDisplay instagramDisplay = new InstagramDisplay();
instagramDisplay.instagramUsers = (List<InstagramUser>)context.Cache[CACHE_KEY];
instagramDisplay.addFilter(u => u.id == instagramId, instagramId);
context.Response.Write(javascriptSerializer.Serialize(instagramDisplay.display());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `ForEach` statement doesn't actually use or store the results of the `Where` method you are running.  You need to build a resulting `IEnumerable<T>`, and filter it in series.

You could write this as:

```
public IEnumerable<InstagramUser> display() { 
    IEnumerable<InstagramUser> users = instagramUsers;
    foreach(var filter in instagramFilters)
        users = users.Where(filter);
    return users;
}
```

Comment: `instagramUsers` is already a public member of `InstagramDisplay`. I thought that by calling `.ForEach()` against `instagramFilters` and enumerating through the filters, chaining the Wheres to `instagramUsers`, was accomplishing exactly that?

Comment: @bflemi3 No - you'd have to write it as: `filter => instagramUsers = instagramUsers.Where(filter).ToList()` (which would mutate the collection)

Comment: @bflemi3 This option just returns the filtered results, without changing the users collection, which is how most APIs function.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. I'm going to give this a shot. Very good info, thank you Reed.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to include users that matches *all* the filters (an `AND` comparison):

```
instagramUsers.Where(u => instagramFilters.All(f => f(u)));
```

If you want to include users that matches 1 or more filters, change the `All` by `Any` in the statement above.

Comment: Are you saying Any would be like OR and All would be like AND?

Comment: Yeap: All = filter1 AND filter2 AND filter3, Any = filter1 OR filter2 OR filter3.

Comment: Yes please, will be good if the downvoter explains his point. My answer do the same thing that the other, but use just 1 line...

Comment: I accepted the other answer because I liked the idea of still keeping the original collection intact when calling `display()`. This answer is very pretty :) though. +1

Comment: @bflemi3 no problem. BTW this approach also keep the collection intact. In fact any Linq expression will not change the source collection ;)